# Displaying content using back-end languages

Tags: php, django, web-deployment, backend

I want to display some content on my website but I don't want to show it in source code. I think it can be done by back-end languages like PHP, Django, ruby etc. Can someone please give me detail information to achieve my target.

edit: I want to print few lines on my website without showing it on source code. So how to do that with back-end languages.

Comment: Still unclear.. please elaborate

Comment: Google Learn Ruby, Learn Django, and don't Google learn PHP because as a former PHP developer I can say PHP is an inferior language compared to Python or Ruby. It is actually a very sloppy and verbose language. Django, Ruby, and PHP all do what you are trying to do. They generate HTML on the server side so you can do things like process forms, and have users log in, and work with a database.